# Facebook event tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I was wondering if it was able to retrieve the tagged pages from an event description. For an example of the tags I'm talking about check the following event: https://www.facebook.com/events/650222158335204/

I would like to be able to retrieve the links to the pages trough the api. But the graph api only returns the following:

```
{
  "id": "650222158335204", 
  "owner": {
    "category": "Record label", 
    "name": "NON Records", 
    "id": "110683022307087"
  }, 
  "name": "THURSDAY 17.10 - ADE - NON RECORDS LABEL NIGHT @ DE BALIE", 
  "description": "Thursday october 17th\nNON Record Label Night\nDe Balie, Amsterdam \n23:00 - 05:00\n\nPresale €8\nDoor €10\n\nPalmbomen dj set\nTlr Creme Org dj set\nAntenna live\nMarius live\nMagnesii dj set\nFreek Fabricius dj set\nHollywood & Vine dj set\nDe Dupe dj set", 
  "start_time": "2013-10-17T23:00:00+0200", 
  "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam", 
  "is_date_only": false, 
  "location": "Café De Balie", 
  "venue": {
    "latitude": 52.363262279216, 
    "longitude": 4.883352093131, 
    "city": "Amsterdam", 
    "state": "", 
    "country": "Netherlands", 
    "id": "216142751734726", 
    "street": "Kleine Gartmanplantsoen 10", 
    "zip": "1017RR"
  }, 
  "privacy": "OPEN", 
  "updated_time": "2013-09-20T10:36:47+0000"
}
```